# Ошибка WebSocketSharp при отключении или отсутствии сервера

Tags: c#, исключения, websocket

Как обработать исключение, если соединение разорвано или сервер не отвечает?

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/client_websocket")
        { 
            ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) => this.Connected();

            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);


            ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>//делаем что-то при ошибке

            ws.OnClose += (sender, e) => //делаем что-то при отключении

            ws.Connect();
            while (true)
            {
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с WebSocketSharp не работал, но я так понял на методе Connect возникает исключение, попробуйте его в `try ... catch` обернуть, да и Send я думаю тоже не лишним будет.

Comment: я пробовал, но всёравно выдаёт. И если разрыв соединения- тоже исключение. Я не пойму- что обрабатывать в try catch?

Comment: А что в Reconnect находится ? Проглядел сразу, OnClose похоже работает, а исключение возникает дальше.

Comment: @"Evgenii Izhboldin" Даже если Reconnect отключить и оставить просто без подписки на события- всёравно вылетает исключение при отключении либо при отсутствии сервера. В Reconnect написано Thread.Sleep(ReconnectionInterval);this.ConnectToServer(Path, ReconnectionInterval);

Comment: А это случаем не лог, который просто в консоль пишется ? Если посмотреть этот WebSocketSharp, он все ошибки в лог пишет.

Comment: @"Evgenii Izhboldin"  ,да- log. Типа это ничего страшного? А можно хоть для "красоты" его выключить?

Comment: log - не страшно да. Насколько я понял беглым взглядом в исходниках, можно `ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Info`, тогда не будут ошибки писаться в лог. Либо в `ws.Log.Output` свой метод передать (который например никуда не пишет), либо настроить запись лога в файл.

Comment: Вам нужен не `Log.Debug`, это как раз метод для вывода лога с уровнем Debug. Выше описал: `ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Info`, это изменит уровень логов.

Comment: @"Evgenii Izhboldin" Написал ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Info;
                ws.Log.Output += (sender, e) => this.Log(); Где метод Log просто ничего не делает. И всёравно выводится log ((

Comment: @"Evgenii Izhboldin"  . Супер. Спасибо))

Comment: Log.Output = (sender, e) => {} (без += думаю нужно, что бы заменить тот что был)

Comment: @"Evgenii Izhboldin" . Ну да- я типа добавлял ещё. Только разбираюсь со всеми этими делами )))

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было просто выключить log. Спасибо @"Evgenii Izhboldin"

```
ws.Log.Output = (LogData data, string path) => { };
```